# Por que la consulta no sale completa en un input php?

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo una consulta de una tabla en mysql,las inserciones se hacen bien,pero cuando consulto se muestran incompletas.Solo se  muestran la primera palabra,en la base de datos esta como tipo text.

```
<?php                   

 $objetoverinformacionF=new ValidarDatosTS();

$verinformacionfa=$objetoverinformacionF->VerDatosFamiliaTS($_POST['hct_id']);

foreach($verinformacionfa as $registro2){

echo  "<tr>



<td> <input  type='hidden' name='fts_id[]' value=".utf8_decode($registro2['fts_id'])."></td>

<td> <input  type='text' name='fts_nombre[]' value=".utf8_decode($registro2['fts_nombre'])."></td>

<td> <input   type='text' name='fts_apellido[]' value=".utf8_decode($registro2['fts_apellido'])."></td>

<td> <input type='text' name='fts_parentezco[]' value=".utf8_decode($registro2['fts_parentezco'])."></td>

<td> <input type='text' name='fts_edad[]' value=".utf8_decode($registro2['fts_edad'])."></td>

<td> <input type='text'  name='fts_escolaridad[]' value=".utf8_decode($registro2['fts_escolaridad'])."></td>

<td> <input  type='text' name='fts_ocupacion[]' value=".utf8_decode($registro2['fts_ocupacion'])."></td>

<td> <input type='text' name='fts_vive[]' value=".utf8_decode($registro2['fts_vive'])."></td>


</tr>";

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Yero puedes editar tu pregunta y colocar el código que tienes desarrollado hasta ahora para poderte ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: Sorry, se habia publicado sin el codigo, ya lo coloque.

Comment: sería genial si colocas una muestra de los datos que esperas obtener y otra de  como los estas obteniendo al momento para comprender mejor lo que ocurre

Comment: Cuando imprimes el valor de la variable **$registro2** directo sin colocarlo en el input te lo imprime bien o desde ahí ya esta cortada la información.

Comment: aCbe de publicar lo que espero obtener de la base de datos, ejemplo, quiero consultar el nombre Yeiny Ropero, solo me muestra Yeiny, Como pueden ver la segunda imagen es del formulario donde consulto pero solo muestra Yeiny, sin el apellido Ropero.

Comment: te sugiero que hagas un var_dump($verinformacionfa);..para visualizar si trae la informacion completa..esto antes del foreach..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es la concatenación. Lo que tienes es:

```
echo  "<tr>
          <!-- algunos <td> -->
          <td> 
            <input  type='hidden' name='fts_escolaridad[]' value=".utf8_decode($registro2['fts_escolaridad'])."></td>

          <!-- otros  <td> -->
      </tr>";
```

Si el campo de escolaridad en la tabla fuese "educación universitaria completa", al hacer:

```
echo "<input value=".utf8_decode($registro2['fts_escolaridad'])."  name='fts_escolaridad[]' type='hidden'>";
```

Se está imprimiendo:

```
<input value=educación universitaria completa name='fts_escolaridad[]' type='hidden'>
```

Cuando en realidad el valor debiera ir entrecomillado, por lo que debieras poner comilla simple antes y después de la concatenación:

```
echo "<input value='".utf8_decode($registro2['fts_escolaridad'])."'  name='fts_escolaridad[]' type='hidden'>";
```

**Bonus Track**

Para mayor abundamiento, el browser puede tolerar que pongas el valor de un atributo sin comillas, pero no tiene cómo saber cuando, luego de un espacio, lo que sigue es un atributo del tag HTML o parte del valor que no se entrecomilló.

Un ejemplo rebuscado, en un iframe con un título como

```
<iframe title="ejemplo recuadro seamless"  src="https..."></iframe>
```

Si lo anterior se escribiera como

```
<iframe title=ejemplo recuadro seamless  src="https..."></iframe>
```

El título sería sólo `ejemplo` mientras que `seamless` se tomaría como [el atributo binario seamless](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/iframe#attr-seamless) (el atributo `seamless` de un iframe le dice al browser que intente homologar estilos para que el iframe se vea mejor integrado). El atributo `recuadro` no existe así que no tiene efecto

Comment: Muchaaaasss gracias , funciono perfectamente a agregar las comillas simples <3.